# how to insert data to mysql database with Jquery ajax and php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn Ajax. I am inserting some data to mysql database from a Html Form by php. It works nicely. But my ajax part does not work. I get the success message but data dont go to my php file.  My html and js code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Insertion of data with Ajax</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" method="POST" action="ajax-save.php">

    Title: <input type="text" name="title" id="title"><br /><br />
    Description: <textarea name="description" id="description" rows="20" cols="40"></textarea><br /><br />
    Url: <input type="text" name="url" id="url"><br /><br />

    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

    </form>

    <script>

     $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#submit").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax-save.php',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            data: $('#myForm').serialize() ,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(){
            alert("success");
            clearForm();
            }
        }); 
           return false;
       });

    });

   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

My php codes are working properly. I have tested it without ajax. Here is my php code.

```
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $db = mysql_select_db('hospital');

    if (isset($_POST['title'])) { $title = $_POST['title'];}
    if (isset($_POST['description'])) { $description = $_POST['description'];}
    if (isset($_POST['url'])) { $url = $_POST['url'];}

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        if(mysql_query("insert into `wp_upload_video` (`id`, `title`, `description`, `url`) values (NULL, '$title', '$description', '$url')"))
            echo "Successfully Inserted";
        else
            echo "Insertion Failed";
    }
```

Please let me know where is my fault.

Comment: It seems to me that your statement `My php codes are working properly` is probably not true.  Also, how do you know it's not working?  In what way is it not working?  MYSQL error log?  PHP error log?  Javascript console errors?  Without that info, it's impossible to say.  Your ajax looks fine though.

Comment: Check the network and console tabs of your browsers' developer tools

Comment: i deemed the priority between "submit" and "click" messed it up so i pasted your code into jsfiddle and added `error: alert("failed")`. finally nothing popped up.

Comment: I have checked my php code without ajax. It works properly. Datas are being inserted to the database. Now I want to prevent the page from reloading. This is why I am using ajax. But nothing is happening. Page remains static. That's my problem. user1167442

Comment: Using ajax.. in what condition would `$_POST['submit']` **not** be set? The ajax only implements upon submit.

Comment: Don't use `mysql` functions anymore! http://php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php. Is the url correct?

Comment: You forgot to `evt.preventDefault()`. Right now your button is just submitting the form normally, AJAX is (probably) not even getting a chance to run.

Comment: Oh... Good God. The Villain was "$_POST['submit']". I have deleted this part just now and everything is working fine :-)  @Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit via ajax on a click of the `submit` button.... that condition is *always* true.

Checking if `$_POST['submit']` is set in the PHP will **always** result in **true** because if it is *not* true the ajax never gets processed.

So... remove the if submit condition in the PHP and handle error notification in the ajax call.

Also, as pointed out by @NiettheDarkAbsol in comments, it's a good idea to add `e.preventDefault()` to the jquery as well to stop the submit button submitting the form as it normally would and allow the jquery to handle the submit (via ajax).